# Insert Into Table Conversion failed

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, types

I need help figuring whats causing the issue.

```
create table ##temp
(   
    city Varchar(100),
    country Varchar(100),
    region Varchar(30),
    load_date datetime
);

insert into ##temp
    select 
        a.city,
        a.country,
        '' as region,
        a.load_date
    from 
        table_1 a
```

Error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Load date example:

```
2017-04-17 00:00:00.000
2017-04-17 00:00:00.000
2017-04-17 00:00:00.000
2017-04-17 00:00:00.000
2017-04-17 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Please add the tag accordingly.

Comment: Can you give some example data?

Comment: Can you try inserting one row into the table with a simple insert statement not a select into? Then provide the insert statement here so maybe someone can see why the insert is failing.

Comment: You could always identify the issue by running a query like the following: `SELECT load_date FROM table_1 WHERE ISDATE(load_date) != 1;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I executed your complete script on my SQL Server Management Studio and it runs without giving a single error. However with the date column you may use `CAST` and `CONVERT`

**Complete SQL Script**

```
CREATE TABLE table_1 (
  city varchar(100),
  country varchar(100),
  region varchar(30),
  load_date datetime
)

INSERT INTO table_1
  VALUES ('Mumbai', 'India', 'West', GETDATE())

SELECT
  *
FROM table_1

CREATE TABLE #temp (
  city varchar(100),
  country varchar(100),
  region varchar(30),
  load_date datetime
);

INSERT INTO #temp
  SELECT
    a.city,
    a.country,
    a.region,
    a.load_date
  FROM table_1 a

SELECT
  *
FROM #temp
--select * from table_1
DROP TABLE #temp
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many formats supported by SQL Server - see the [MSDN Books Online on CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx). Most of those formats are **dependent** on what settings you have - therefore, these settings might work some times - and sometimes not.

The way to solve this is to use the (slightly adapted) **ISO-8601 date format** that is supported by SQL Server - this format works **always** - regardless of your SQL Server language and dateformat settings.

The [ISO-8601 format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878.aspx) is supported by SQL Server comes in two flavors:

- `YYYYMMDD` for just dates (no time portion); note here: **no dashes!**, that's very important! `YYYY-MM-DD` is **NOT** independent of the dateformat settings in your SQL Server and will **NOT** work in all situations!

or:

- `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` for dates and times - note here: this format *has* dashes (but they *can* be omitted), and a fixed `T` as delimiter between the date and time portion of your `DATETIME`.

This is valid for SQL Server 2000 and newer.

If you use SQL Server **2008** or newer and the `DATE` datatype (only `DATE` - **not** `DATETIME`!), then you can indeed also use the `YYYY-MM-DD` format and that will work, too, with any settings in your SQL Server.

Don't ask me why this whole topic is so tricky and somewhat confusing - that's just the way it is. But with the `YYYYMMDD` format, you should be fine for any version of SQL Server and for any language and dateformat setting in your SQL Server.

The recommendation for SQL Server **2008** and newer is to use `DATE` if you only need the date portion, and `DATETIME2(n)` when you need both date and time. You should try to start phasing out the `DATETIME` datatype if ever possible

So in your case, I'm pretty sure everything will work fine **if**

- you change the datatype of `load_date` in your temp table to `datetime2(3)`
- **OR:** you change the format of the strings you're importing into a `datetime` to `2017-04-17T00:00:00.000`